# What is the most amazing chess position you have seen?

Tags: analysis, tactics, studies

What is the most amazing chess position you have seen?

I have been wanting to ask this question for a while, but feared it would be closed. Since the "Uniquely Satisfying Puzzle" and "What is the most complex chess problem?" questions were not closed, I am going to post it. I hope that this is not voted closed as it is a chance to share some amazing positions.

Please post only one position per answer, but feel free to answer multiple times.

Comment: Yes, it is opinion-based, but not the first opinion-based question that you have let through. There should be a way to share interesting positions with the community without having to contrive some stupid question to make it fit the rules. There are enough questions that are "out there" already.

Comment: @RewanDemontay Thanks. I wanted everyone to get some, and to have the opportunity to see some cool positions. I hope you liked them. There is plenty of junk asked here, so at least this is some nice chess. I have no problem with it, but the "question" yesterday, "Uniquely Satisfying Puzzle" was not even a question. :)

Comment: @RewanDemontay By the way, although I did think about people having the opportunity to get some upvotes, the main reason I wanted each post separate was so we would know which ones people liked the most.

Comment: I do not intend to do that. You have not been as free with your edits of material and content. Just discussing it worked. I never had any problems with other types of edits, like spelling, grammar, and formatting. In fact, I have appreciated you formatting a few of mine earlier. I finally figured out the [FEN} problems I was having, so I have not needed that as much. You and I seem to be OK too.

Comment: I always liked this one: https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1094915, `23...Qg3!!`.

Comment: @Akavall I also that one.

Comment: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](/help/dont-ask) *avoid asking subjective questions where … every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”*

Comment: @Glorfindel I am well-aware, but with all the, and I was nice the first time, STUPID questions that get asked, how about a question, even if it is subjective, that actually demonstrates some beautiful chess. I can also go one further: Since chess is part art, and hardly an exact science, short of forced mate questions, EVERY question here is subjective to some degree, let alone, the answers. There needs to be a way to allow this type of question.

Comment: Perhaps a dedicated chatroom might work? See also [Give each site a parallel site for polling, recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383/295232) on Meta.SE and related topics.

Comment: @Glorfindel P.S. You guys are also VERY subjective, and sometimes very hypocritical, as to what you let stand or close. Read my preamble about why I decided to post this in the first place, and compare those...there is not much difference. It is is good chess, then it should stand.

Comment: I guess what I am saying is that it is chess, and anything that furthers it, and that includes questions that are subjective, should be allowed. While that rule may work for other StackExchanges, we should change it, and loosen it for this board. If someone wants recommendations for the "best" database software, so be it, but I guess that logic is out the window on a chess board...oh, the irony.

Comment: Maybe the title can be changed (perhaps exclude "most"), but I think having a Q/A of amazing positions would be interesting and valuable. I really don't think there is a lot of disagreement on what an "amazing" position is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

White to win. L Kubbel 1927

```
 [FEN "8/8/1p6/kp3p2/p7/1PP1p2B/5p2/5R1K w - - 0 1"]


 1. Ra1 $1 {Threatening Bf1 stopping the pawns.} e2 2. Bf1 $1 e1=Q 3. Rxa4+! bxa4 4. b4#
```

Comment: This is my favorite. Incredible economy of forces.

Answer (score 6):

And one last one from a real game. Black to move and win.

```
 [Date "2003.??.??"]
 [White "Ibrahim"]
 [Black "Ibarra"]
 [FEN "3q4/1p1n1pk1/p1r1p1p1/2P1Pn1p/1P1N1P2/B5rP/5RPK/Q3R3 b - - 0 1"]

 1... Nxd4 $1 2. Kxg3 (2. Qxd4 Rxa3 3. Rd1 Qh4 {is just up a piece.}) 2... Qh4+ $3 3. Kxh4 Nf5+ 4. Kg5 Nf8 5. g4 {and there is no defense to....} Nh7#
```

Answer (score 4):

A missed variation from the game Najer-Nepomniachi, Moscow 2006. Black to move and win.

```
 [FEN "5rk1/3R1p2/4p2p/4P1pP/2q4r/P1n1BQ2/2P2PP1/4R1K1 b - - 0 1"]

 1... g4 2. Qg3 Qf1+ $3 3. Rxf1 (3. Kxf1 Rh1#) 3... Ne2#
```

Answer (score 1):

White to move and draw. Y. Afek 1978

```
 [FEN "8/5N1p/8/b6p/7P/6KP/7R/4kr2 w - - 0 1"]

 1. Ne5 $1 {Rf7 and Bc7 are both threatened.} Bc7 2. Rh1 $3 Rxh1 (2... Bxe5+ 3. Kg2 Rxh1 4. Kxh1 {And while black is up a piece, and can win all of white's pawns, this is a known drawn position since the white king cannot be ousted from the corner of the "wrong" bishop.}) 3. Kg2 Rf1 4. Nd3+ $1 Ke2 5. Nc1+ $1 Ke1 6. Nd3+ Ke2 7. Nc1+ Rxc1 {Stalemate!!}
```

Comment: These are all from Dvoretsky's last book, "Chess Tests". Just amazing positions.